# Adobe Acrobat Reader DC how to prevent update from 32bit to 64bit

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

We have a problem with our customers with Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.

The point is that many programs instaled on customers PC use Acrobat Reader ActiveX object to display PDF documents, and as they are 32-bit so they must have installed AcrobatReader 32-bit version as well.

It has been happening for some time that Acrobat Reader is updating to the 64-bit version and we have to connect to the client and reinstall Adobe Acrobat Reader.

Is there any way around this problem?
How to prevent Acrobat Reader 32-bit from updating to 64-bit?

Answer (score 2):

Set in the registry key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\FeatureLockDown`,
the value of the item DWORD-32 `bUpdateToSingleApp` to `0`.

This should disable the upgrade to 64 bit.

Comment: Below, I have made a reply to this report with a screen of my computer.

Comment: @PiotrT - You should have edited your question instead of submitting an answer that doesn’t actually answer your question.

Comment: @PiotrT: You should have done as Ramhound said, but I can still see the deleted post. Yes, you should create the item.